# Exception defined in thrift

Tags: thrift

I have a thrift file written by some one else, where there are some dataformat exceptions. I have java generated files by thrift compiler which I barely understood.I am trying to validate some date input and it should throw that exception when input is not valid. I am really not sure whether I can use that exception or not.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the Thrift IDL file from which the code was generated. If the IDL is not present, the Details can be obtained by having a look into the generated deserialization methods for each function call, typically they are named somthing like recv_Foo() and recv_Bar().

```
exception MyError
{
  1: i32  code
}

exception UglyError
{
  1: i64  what_a_mess
}

Service Sample
{
  i32 Foo() throws (1: MyError me)
  i32 Bar() throws  (1: MyError me, 2: UglyError ue)
}
```

Foo() can throw only MyError, while Bar() can throw both exceptions. If you throw an UglyError while processing a Foo() call, the Client will not see this error (but probably another exception).